# Not able to pass special characters while running helm set command

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I was running helm set command for multi parameter values and parameter value is given below.
Please note that this value is to use below parameters to run the Control M Job. I am pretty sure that
Helm command looks for escape character when field name is separated with comma which I used it in PARAM2, however one of the field is defined as emp.type in this parameter because data is coming from Salesforce. I am not sure if I need to use escape character in this field along with
PARAM1 & PARAM3. While running it throws an error as  "Illegal Space Character"

- PARAM1: CTM_SOURCE_FILTER="parent.type in ('RCSA_Assessment__c','RCSA_Disagreement__c','RCSA_Experience__c','RCSA_Gap__c')"
- PARAM2: CTM_SOURCE_FIELDS="body,abcd,defg,pqrs,adfr,\emp.type"
- PARAM3: CTM_SOURCE_FIELD_EXPRESSION="$.mapKeys((value,key)=>key == "emp.type" ? "emp.type" :key)"

Please let me know how to handle special characters while passing in helm set command

Comment: If you think your value might contain punctuation, there are enough syntactic quirks in `helm install --set` that I might avoid it entirely.  Write a JSON or YAML file instead and pass that through `helm install -f`.